# Make Doctrine skip fields/columns during INSERT INTO that are read-only

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, persistence, hydration

I have a PostgreSQL table `t` with columns `t1`, `t2`, …. I need to filter a collection of the entities *before* hydrating all objects by Doctrine due to efficiency reasons. However, the `Criteria` class of Doctrine is too limited, because it must work on the level of PHP objects (after hydration) and at the SQL level (after hydration). Hence, I decided to create a SQL view that essentially mirrors the table `T` and adds an additional, dynamic column that evaluates the expression at the SQL level. Hence I have

```
CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT t.*, (t.t1 <> t.t2) AS flag FROM t AS t;
```

(N.b.: The above boolean expression for `flag` is actually much more complex. It serves as a place-holder here.)

The Doctrine entity `T` is linked to the view instead of the table and has an additional field `$flag`. I use `ORM\ChangeTrackingPolicy( "NOTIFY" )` on this entity class such that the field `$flag` is never marked as dirty and Doctrine never includes it into an `UPDATE` statement. At the PHP level the field `$flag` is kept in sync with the fields that form the boolean expression by means of proper getter/setters.

PosgreSQL supports `INSERT INTO`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` on views if the fields of the views are elementary expressions of the same table.

The problem: If a new entity is persisted for the first time Doctrine includes the field `$flag` into the the `INSERT INTO` statement, even if `$flag` is marked as not dirty. This triggers the following SQL exception: "ERROR: cannot insert into column "flag" of view "v" DETAIL: View columns that are not columns of their base relation are not updatable."

Is there any way to tell Doctrine to not include this column? Is there a way to mark a column as read-only?

Answer (score 2):

For those who would encounter the same issue like me. Starting with Doctrine version `>2.11`, `@Column` annotation has introduced new useful options ([docs reference](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/annotations-reference.html)) :

- `updatable`
- `insertable`

Fields with these options set to `false` are now ignored in the generated SQL query.